# Can't get permissions right for EC2 Linux running WordPress

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

I have successfully setup my WordPress site on an Amazon EC2 instance.

However, I can't seem to figure out why I have to choose "either/or" for permissions.

I followed the tutorial posted here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

...and it seems to say that the permissions set are for the group, but I'm not seeing it work that way.

When I run the following, I can login with e2-user and copy files, can upload via SSH (WinSCP), etc:

```
sudo chown -R root:www /var/www
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} +
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
```

But then, when I'm logged into WordPress, and I try to upload files or add plugins, I get the following:

> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

So, I can go back to the console and the following allows the installs to take place no problem:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www
```

So my question is... Isn't there a way to give permissions to BOTH ec2-user AND apache?

At the recommendation of a responder, I confirmed that both users are in the `www` group:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ groups ec2-user
ec2-user : ec2-user wheel www
[ec2-user ~]$ groups apache
apache : apache www
```

Some more clarification regarding the other ways to check...

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
ec2-user:x:500:500:EC2 Default User:/home/ec2-user:/bin/bash
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin

$ cat /etc/group
www:x:501:ec2-user,apache
```

Does this help?

Comment: read the error. WP can't even log into your server to begin with, meaning that fiddling with file permissions is pointless.

Comment: i'm not sure i follow.  what i'm saying is that fiddling with permissions DOES solve the problem.  i'd rather not have to go back and forth every time i want to upload a file via SSH or install a plugin.  i just want to have two users (or one group) have permissions to the same directory at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A user can be part of multiple groups, so create another group and give group permissions to the directories you want to access, like a sftp group or something, Hope it helps....

```
usermod -a -G grp1,grp2 user
```

Comment: But both are part of the `www` group (i think?)... somehow im not getting group permissions but instead im getting individual permissiona.

Comment: can you make sure if they are part of www group, check the groupID in /etc/group and compare it with the user in /etc/passwd.  

user:x:500:200:User:/home/user:/bin/bash
200 is the Group ID

Comment: i just updated the question... i *think* i confirmed that they are both in the www group...